# Ruby Teaspoon Unknown default suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, teaspoon

I run in my rails project

```
rake teaspoon
```

and error output is

```
Teaspoon::UnknownSuite: Unknown suite "default\"
```

can any one explain me what this problem means?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with teaspoon on Windows in version 0.8.0.

https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon/issues/271

In `lib/teaspoon/drivers/phantomjs_driver.rb` you need to change `url.shellescape` to `url`